# Understanding properties in a UINavigationController with viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that I reuse to push photos and comments looping over each other through the navigation controller.

In my `MyViewController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableAttributedString *pLabel;
```

In my `MyViewController.m`:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound)
    {
        // A photo function gets the right label
        _pLabel = // function gets correct label I want
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _pLabel = // is already set
}
```

I click on MyViewController once and set `mvc.pLabel = @"1st one"`. Then I click a button to create a new MyViewController and set `mvc.pLabel = @"2nd";`

Then when I click the Back button `viewWillDisappear` gets called and my dictionary sets `pLabel = @"1st"`.  Then `viewWillAppear` gets run to show the first navigation controller view and pLabel = @"2nd";

Why isn't `viewWillDisappear` not saving the pLabel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is bound to 1 instance of `MyViewController` so when you pop your second view controller you'll set the property of the `MyViewController` that will disappear and not to the one that'll become visible.

If you don't keep a reference on the `MyViewController` that disappears there are no reason to update one of its label, since you'll probably show a fresh new instance of `MyViewController` next time.